# Understanding derivative $f_{ij}$ in a riemannian manifold.

Tags: geometry, derivatives, riemannian-geometry

In Riemannian manifold, let $\{e_1, \cdots e_n\}$ be an orthonormal frame. Then there is a dual coframe $\{w^1, \cdots, w^n\}$.

$f_i := \nabla f( e_i)$

$f_{ij} : = \nabla^2f(e_i, e_j)$

$f_{ijk} : = \nabla^3 f(e_i, e_j, e_k)$

$\vdots$

I want to show that $f_i = e_i(f)$ and $f_{ij} = e_j(f_i)$.
The first identity is trivial:
$$f_i = \nabla f( e_i) = e_i(f)$$
To show that the second identity holds, I tried as below.
\begin{align*}
f_{ij}=f_{ji} & = \nabla^2 f (e_j ,e_i)\\
& = \nabla_{e_j,e_i}^2 f\\
& = \nabla_{e_j} \nabla_{e_i}f - \nabla_{\nabla_{e_j}e_i}f\\
&=(f_i)_j -  \nabla_{\nabla_{e_j}e_i}f
\end{align*}
I want to show that $\nabla_{\nabla_{e_j}e_i}f = 0$. How can I show this?

Comment: I didn't see why it should be zero btw.

Comment: It is not true that $f_{ij} = e_i(f_j)$

Comment: @Arctic Char Then, even if i took an orthonormal frame, is there an additional term like $f_{ij}=(f_i)_j + $ something ?

Comment: Yes. Or you could choose a normal coordinates around a point $p$, then $f_{ij} =(f_i)_j $ at $p$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you!